# az aks install-connector fails "--name uknow parameter"

Tags: azure-container-service

Based on: https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/azure-aci#Validate-the-Virtual-Kubelet-ACI-provider

I run the following command (of cos my internal names for rg, cluster):

****az aks install-connector --resource-group  --name  --os-type windows****

but it fails:

*--name parameter unknow*

I was trying many tricks and nothing helpls.
any idea  :) ???

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same result if running from Azure cloud shell. What the heck ?!

Comment: Looks like helm is broken as well: helm install --name "virtual-kubelet" "https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet/raw/master/charts/virtual-kubelet-latest.tgz" `
  --set provider=azure `
  --set providers.azure.targetAKS=true `
  --set providers.azure.masterUri=https://dariusaks01-0447bc02.hcp.eastus2.azmk8s.io:443

Comment: above returns: Error: unknown flag: --name

Comment: Any more questions? Does my answer solve your problem? If yes please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the possible reason is that the CLI command is conflicted with helm 3. If you use the helm 2, then it works well.

Actually, the CLI command uses the helm to install the chart in the AKS cluster. See more details from the parameter `--chart-url` of the command [`az aks install-connector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-install-connector). So the other solution is that use the helm to install the chart yourself. You can download the chart and then install it. You can get the chart [here](https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/virtual-kubelet/tree/master/charts).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the enable-addons command instead of install-connector.

You can follow the official instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/virtual-nodes-cli#enable-virtual-nodes-addon

```
az aks enable-addons \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myAKSCluster \
    --addons virtual-node \
    --subnet-name myVirtualNodeSubnet
```

The install-connector was a command set used during preview, which is set for removal.

This has been called out on the virtual-kubelet project here as being a deprecated command: https://github.com/virtual-kubelet/azure-aci/pull/31